# About stackoverflow comment

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

This might appear silly, but I have been wondering for a while, how can I put code inside a comment in stackoverflow. I haven't been able to figure this out. I have seen users putting those grayish blocks in a comment.

I tried (<pre><code>) but that didn't work.

Regards

Comment: you mean `like this`?

Comment: This belongs on `meta`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backquotes to insert code in comments, just as you might insert inline code in a question or answer: `printf("here is some code\n");`

Comment: @Ether - I tried doing this. Text wrapped in `backquotes` displays a gray block in question or answer, but in comments it displays a `highlighted box`. How do I get the grey box in a comment?

Comment: @ShiVik: what dis the difference between a highlighted box and a grey box?  Do they both use a monospaced font?

Comment: Yes. highlighted box is just white in background, it appears hightlighted when I hover the mouse over the comment which has it. Grey box is always highlighted grey whether I hover mouse over it or not.

Answer (score 1):

use backticks "`" <code here> "`".

BTW, this belongs on meta.

Answer (score 1):

Putting four spaces before the code will automatically generate the code block. Inside of a comment, you can wrap it with `` ` `` and it will demarcate the code. Or simply mark up the code that you want to be laid out as code and press the button with the `101010` label.

Answer (score -2):

You can't, because the comments only support limited markdown tags.

Stop with the down votes - this was migrated while i was in the middle of editing it!! What i was busy clarifying is that it isn't a full code block - you don't get syntax coloring etc, just the highlighted background.

For the FAQ on comments [check here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work). For the details on allowed markdown, [check here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/).

Comment: You were probably downvoted because the OP mentioned specifically what he was looking for: "I have seen users putting those grayish blocks in a comment."